# Need help fixing a random sentence generator that uses for loops and list's

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that will form random sentences that can be passed repeatedly to a for loop to generate a different output each time by using random.choice(), variables, and list's. An example looks like this:

```
list_0 = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]
variable_0 = random.choice(list_0)

list_1 = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]
variable_1 = random.choice(list_1)

list_2 = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]
variable_2 = random.choice(list_2)
```

After I form my list's of subject's, conjunction's, noun's, verb's, ect.., I then pass them to variables equivalent to one random choice from said list. at this point there are a couple of ways you can print the sentence the idea being that the program will select a random word from each list and print them out in order of _0 _1 and _2 so the sentence will be random but grammatical.
I've tried listing all the variables and randomizing those like so

```
list_3 = [list_0, list_1, list_2]
random.choice(list_3)
```

however this would only print one choice at a time, and I need entire random sentences, so then I tried

```
list_3 =  [list_0 + list_1 + list_2]
```

and while this does print the entire random sentence, once its inside the for loop it only prints once before stopping which I assume is because it's not being told to evaluate more than once, example:

```
for line in list_3:
    try:
        print(line)
        if line !='\n':
            #do function
            sleep(10)
        else:
            pass
    except:
            #do function
            sleep(2)
```

even with the sleep function the script stops after 1 iteration, so then I tried a 'while True' loop at the top and while this forced the function the print more than once, the output was duplicate rather than another random sentence. Example:

```
while True:    
    for line in list_3:
      try:
        print(line)
        if line !='\n':
            do function
            sleep(10)
        else:
            pass
      except:
            #do function
            sleep(2)
```

This is where I am stuck, from what I can see the random function is only passing one random sentence to my for loop, so when the while loop runs the for loop again it just prints the previous sentence. Is there anything I can do to pass my for loop a different sentence than the previous one for each new iteration? I would love help I am still very new.

Comment: since list_3 only contains 1 element, random.choice() can never return more than 1 result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a concise version:

```
import random

words = [["Two","Three", "Four"],
         ["red","yellow","green"],
         ["cats","dogs","zebras"],
         ["jumped.", "danced.", "wrote poetry."]]

for i in range(5):
    print( ' '.join([random.choice(w) for w in words]))
```

Typical output:

```
Three yellow cats jumped.
Three yellow zebras jumped.
Four red zebras jumped.
Two green zebras danced.
Four green dogs wrote poetry.
```

Note how you can directly create a list of lists without having to assign the inner lists to variables.

The key to understanding the code is understanding the list comprehension

```
[random.choice(w) for w in words]
```

This is essentially syntactic sugar for something like:

```
sentence = []
for w in words:
    sentence.append(random.choice(w))
```

Finally, the use of `' '.join()` is a nice way to take a list of words and join them together with a space between.

Comment: Thanks a lot man this really simplifies things, my code was giving me a huge headache!

Answer (score -1):

Try this with the code at the top outside the while loop commented or deleted

```
while True:  
    list_0 = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4",]
    variable_0 = random.choice(list)

    list_1 = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4",]
    variable_1 = random.choice(list)

    list_2 = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4",]
    variable_2 = random.choice(list)
    list_3 =  [list_0 + list_1 + list_2]
    for line in list_3:
      try:
        print(line)
        if line !='\n':
            do function
            sleep(10)
        else:
            pass
      except:
            #do function
            sleep(2)
```

Comment: so I should wrap my entire code in a while loop? i guess i'm a little confused